# Plotly showing stacked values in Y-axis

Tags: csv, graph, plotly

I am beginner at using plotly and I am trying to plot a graph for a csv file. The graph must have a constant X axis values but the Y axis values changes for different column. The sample data for the graph is shared below for reference:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -1489.6275 | -1489.6774 |
| 2 | -1489.6273 | -1489.6282 |
| 4 | -1489.6085 | -1489.6505 |
| 6 | -1489.6267 | -1489.6266 |

The kind of graph I would want would look like this (Sample Image showing different values of Y to a constant X-axis):

[image: Fig2]

I tried running a simple code as below:

```
f1 = go.Figure(
    data = [
        go.Scatter(x=t, y=z0, name="first"),
        go.Scatter(x=t, y=z2, name ='s')
    ],
    layout = {"xaxis": {"title": "x axis"}, "yaxis": {"title": "y axis"}, "title": "My title"}
)
f1
```

I got a graph like this:
[image: Fig.]

The graph is stacking the values of the different columns I am trying to plot.

Comment: can you explain a bit further with a reproducible example? are you expecting there to be more columns plotted? also what are the variables `t`, `z0`, and `z2`? can you provide some or all of these variables in your question?

Comment: @DerekO the '''t, z0, z2 ''' in question have varying values. Also, I expect more columns to be plotted on the same figure.

Comment: are `z0` and `z2` lists of multiple column names?

Comment: They just contain a list of values in their respective columns. they do not contain sub-column names. @DerekO

Comment: @DerekO I even tried using Seaborn to plot this graph. But, apparently, the Y axis seemed to be going wrong. (Also, the ideal graph I posted is the graph I am trying to obtain. However, I won't be able to provide values of the other columns)

Comment: if `z0` and `z2` are each a list of values, then you'll only get one trace for each `go.Scatter` you pass to data – if you want more than two traces, you'll need to provide more `go.Scatter` arguments to `data`